# What are my options for creating a touch enabled scatter gallery for iOS?

Tags: iphone, gallery, photo

I am not asking for someone to write the code, but basically point me in the right direction. What tools are available? Can I use cocos2d or box2d or should I just use openGL?

Here is a variation of what I want to create for the iPhone:
[Flash Gallery](http://activeden.net/item/dynamic-photographers-xml-portfolio/full_screen_preview/44169)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, there's no reason why you couldn't do that using standard UIViews and Core Animation. I think a 2D sprite engine isn't really appropriate for that (Cocos2D, etc), so it would either be OpenGL or UIViews. And UIViews will be considerably simpler, and as it's all flat images OpenGL is a bit overkill. Performance should be just as good with UIViews also.

I don't see anything in the flash page you linked to that couldn't be done using standard UIViews and Core Animation. With some gesture recognizers attached to each view you could easily get that functionality. Look at Apple's Photos app on the iPad to see what you can do just with UIViews.